# Syntax to specify to spark-shell a query file (with elasticsearch-spark connector)

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

For spark-shell command, I want to specify a file for the spark.es.query parameter:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[4] 
    --jars ~/spark/jars/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar 
    --conf spark.es.nodes="localhost" --conf spark.es.resource="myindex/mytype" 
    --conf spark.es.query="/home/pat/spark/myquery.json"
```

In the shell:

```
scala> import org.elasticsearch.spark._
scala> val es_rdd = sc.esRDD("myindex/mytype")
scala> es_rdd.first()
```

Output I get:

```
17/02/04 07:41:31 ERROR TaskContextImpl: Error in TaskCompletionListener
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot determine 
specified query - doesn't appear to be URI or JSON based and location 
[/home/pat/spark/myquery.json] cannot be opened
```

Of course, file exists on the path. Is it the good way to specify a query file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because spark and the es-connector expects that's the file path is passed as a URI :

```
SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[4] \
 --jars ~/spark/jars/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-5.1.2.jar \
 --conf spark.es.nodes="localhost" \
 --conf spark.es.resource="myindex/mytype" \
 --conf spark.es.query="file:///home/pat/spark/myquery.json"
```

Comment: I'm glad it works @Patrick , can you check your other questions please ? I have left a comment and answer